# How to find out if a document has been signed

Tags: docusignapi

In my returnUrl handler, I am using list documents.

In the returned array, how can I figure out if the document has been signed or not?

Thanks!

Comment: See my answer for additional info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your return url handler will be called with a query parameter `event` as discussed in Inbar's answer.

But you should **not** use the query parameter for making business decisions since a bad guy could easily call your return url and simply tack on an **event=signing_complete** query parameter--spoofing your application.

Instead, when your application needs to know if the envelope has been signed or not, it has two categories of options:

#### Ask DocuSign

Your app can call the [Envelopes::get](https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/reference/Envelopes/Envelopes/get) method to determine the current status of the envelope. Other API methods can also be used for this functionality.

Design your app such that you do not call DocuSign about a particular envelope more often than once every 15 minutes since such behavior is considered polling and is not allowed.

#### Webhook: DocuSign will call your app

You can set up a webhook with DocuSign so that the eSignature platform will call your application when the envelope is complete (signed by all the signers, etc).

Use the DocuSign webhook HMAC feature to guarantee that the notification message came from DocuSign (was not spoofed) and that it was not altered in transmission.

By using AWS or equivalent, you can easily receive the notification messages behind the firewall, with no firewall changes. And AWS will not charge you for the first million notification messages per month. See the connect-* repos on github.com/docusign

#### Dashboards

If your app wants to present a dashboard to a business decision maker about the status of your envelopes, then relying on the `event` query parameter is fine. But before your app does anything that costs real money, eg initiate goods or services to be provided to a customer, make sure that the envelope has been signed by using one of the two techniques above.

Answer (score 0):

The URL you get back from DocuSign has an event parameter and looks like this:

```
http://www.acme.com?event=signing_complete
```

signing_complete means it was signed.

https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/guides/features/embedding has the full list of other events in the "Determining Recipient Action" section of the article.

Comment: The `event` query parameter should not be used for business decisions since a clever bad guy could spoof it. See my answer fo more info.